# Can't see the printf() output while debugging in VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, debugging, gcc, printf

I tried running the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{

   for (int fehr = 0; fehr < 300; fehr = fehr + 20)
   {
        printf("%3d\t%6f\n", fehr, (5.0 / 9.0) * (fehr - 32.0));
   }
}
```

When running normally, I get the following output, as expected:

```
 0     -17.777778
 20     -6.666667
 40     4.444444 
 60     15.555556
 80     26.666667
100     37.777778
120     48.888889
140     60.000000
160     71.111111
180     82.222222
200     93.333333
220     104.444444
240     115.555556
260     126.666667
280     137.777778
```

But when I debug the program line by line (and inside the loop), I can't see the output anywhere.
The compiler is `gcc` and the debugger is `cppdbg`.
Any ideas?

Comment: related, but not an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716296/11107541

Comment: What is in your launch.json?